# Issue with wildcard directory search

Tags: java, file, wildcard

I am running into an issue with trying to validate the existence of a file in a directory utilizing a wildcard.

The method is supposed to determine if a file with name `FAACIFP_(year)(cycle).DAT` could be found in the current directory.

I've tried running a `PathMaker.matches("glob:FAACIFP_18")` with IF/ELSE and when I tested it, it would always evaluate TRUE. So, I tried a lambda function, and it won't find the file.

Shouldn't the lambda below print the file name, or am I misunderstanding/misusing it?

```
static void getCnvrtdCifpName() throws IOException{
        String cnvFileName = "FAACIFP_"+Year.now()
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy"));
        Path cnvFilePath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        Files.find(cnvFilePath,0,(path,attr) -> 
                path.getFileName().startsWith(cnvFileName)).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("EVALUATING METHOD....\t SEARCH PATH: "+cnvFilePath
                +" \n\t\t\t FILE STRING: "+cnvFileName);
    }
```

Output:

```
run:
Located RAW CIFP file FAACIFP18

EVALUATING METHOD....    SEARCH PATH: C:\Users\u314170\Documents\Personal\Java\NetBeans\A424Parser 
             FILE STRING: FAACIFP_18
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: `FAACIFP18` does not have an `_`(`FAACIFP_18`)?

Comment: That's my bad....I have two methods running, one to look for "FAACIFP(year)" which works and outputs "RAW CIFP file FAACIFP(year)".  It's the second method that looks to see if the file was converted to "FAACIFP_(year)(cycle)".  I have everything else working, just not the find with wildcards.

Comment: Ha! `path.getFileName().startsWith(cnvFileName)` should be `path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(cnvFileName)` and depth probably 1.

Comment: Thanks, Joop!  I figured out another method to accomplish my goal.  But, I am going to test your method so I can gain better experience.  One thing I definitely am struggling with is the order of method-chaining.  That, and rethinking in terms of OOP.  This old dog started programming in MS-BASIC and dabbled here/there in Pascal and C.  So, OOP is a new way of looking at things.

Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:
1) change the maxdepth in your find call to 1 (from zero)
2) path.getFileName() returns a full pathname. You will want to evaluate only the filename portion (look at getName(getNameCount()-1)

Comment: I tried that and got the same output.  It's still not doing the println the filename of the lambda.  I only get the path and search string.

Comment: I can't really tell what your current code looks like, but I would try the following.
1) replace the filter "path.getFileName().startsWith(cnvFileName)" with true , then you will see all the files in the 'user.dir' directory. As I mentioned in my first comment these will be full path names, not just file names.  2) You may want to also printout the value of user.dir, this may not be what you think it is. 3) make corrections to the directory name to search if needed, and make adjustments to your filter code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestions, I finally found a resolution:

```
static void getCnvrtdCifpName() throws IOException{
        String cnvFileName = "FAACIFP_"+Year.now()
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy"));
        Path cnvFilePath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        DirectoryStream<Path> cnvFileStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(cnvFilePath,cnvFileName+"*");
        System.out.println("EVALUATING METHOD....\t SEARCH PATH: "+cnvFilePath
                +" \n\t\t\t FILE STRING: "+cnvFileName);
        List cnvDirList = new ArrayList();
        for(Path file: cnvFileStream){
            cnvDirList.add(file.getFileName().toString());
        }
        cnvFileStream.close();
        System.out.println(cnvDirList);
    }
```

With output:

```
run:
EVALUATING METHOD....    SEARCH PATH: C:\Users\u314170\Documents\Personal\Java\NetBeans\A424Parser 
             FILE STRING: FAACIFP_18
[FAACIFP_1808.dat, FAACIFP_1810.txt, FAACIFP_1811.txt]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I really enjoy the problem-solving challenges while learning Java.  There are so many resources out there, and many different ways to resolve an issue.